# How to fetch external dependencies in bazel

Tags: build, bazel, external-dependencies, http-archive

I want bazel to fetch an external dependency from a URL. The file is an rpm file.
I added this in the WORKSPACE file in root dir:

```
http_archive(
    name = "mylib",
    url = "someURL/somefile.rpm",
    build_file = "example.BUILD"
)
```

When I try:

```
bazel fetch @mylib//...
```

It says:

```
"com.google.devtools.build.lib.syntax.EvalException: Expected a file with a .zip, .jar, .war, .tar, .tar.gz, .tgz, .tar.xz, .txz, or .tar.bz2 suffix"
```

Basically it is not allowing to download rpm deps. How can I achieve this ?
How to download external dependency of type rpm.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to fetch an `.rpm` file, but it seems that bazel only accepts archive files with the suffixes `.zip, .jar, .war, .tar, .tar.gz, .tgz, .tar.xz, .txz, or .tar.bz2`.

Comment: Such information, much wow :P ! That's obvious. I was asking how to achieve it.

Comment: @ShayanAnwar: you could try using `http_file` and unpack it yourself

Answer (score 0):

You certainly figured it out by now.
Like @sebastian-nowak commented, you can do something like:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_file")

http_file(
    name = "mylib",
    url = "someURL/somefile.rpm"
)
```

and in your `example.BUILD`, reference it with `@mylib//file`

(Source: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/repo/http.html#http_file)